# Calculating speeding limit with google maps

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

I have latitudes longitudes and speed data. Now I want to find the speed limit of that area and know if their is over speeding in my data or not. So is their an api or on google map by using which I can determine the overspeeding thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tag is probably irrelevant to the question.

Just to answer your yes/no question and as you mentioned Google Maps Platform please refer to this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits

Apparently you'll need to subscribe to the Premium Plan of Google Maps APIs.

An alternative could be:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed